# Better way of doing the following in nodejs: Comparing if specific key value pairs exist in rows of a imported csv or array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

**Issue:**

I want to take an object which has 4 key value pairs and compare it to an array of objects which also contains these 4 keys. I want to check if the values for the 4 keys in the array of objects MATCH the values in the reference object.

**Current implementation**

The code below works, as a test it produces an array which checks if the "Code" key value matches that of the reference object "testCheck". The code should be expanded to also check that the year and month are for current year and month and id from the reference object (I know how to get the year and month from node).

**What I want to know is there a better way of doing this, something more scale friendly maybe or just better written code?**

**toDB** -> in production, this will come from the DB, which admin can dynamically manage through an admin portal.

**testarr** -> this is just a snippet, but in production this will come from an uploaded csv.

**testCheck**-> in production, this object will be created from data in the DB, which once again should be managed by the admin.

**Code**

```js
let testarr = [
  {
    Account: "1110-000",
    Description: "Cash - Operating",
    Amount: "-2,733,864.88",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
  {
    Account: "1116-000",
    Description: "Cash in Trust",
    Amount: "35,431.85",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
  {
    Account: "1170-000",
    Description: "Petty Cash",
    Amount: "0",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
];

let toDB = { code: "cat", id: "cat12345" };
let testCheck = {
  Code: toDB["code"],
  Year: "2020",
  Month: "1",
  Id: toDB["id"],
};
confirmTheSame = (data) => {
  return data.map((x) => {
    if (x["Code"] === testCheck["Code"]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};

let result = confirmTheSame(testarr);
console.log(result);
```

**EDIT 1**

Found this works better in mapping the testCheck with the array of objects and produced a arrays of boolean for each row (array of arrays) but maybe not the best way of doing this? Leaving this here for your thoughts..

```js
confirmTheSame = (data) => {
  return data.map((x) => {
    return Object.keys(testCheck).map((y) => {
      if(x[y]===testCheck[y]){
          return true
      }
      else{
          return false
      }

    });
  });
};
```

Comment: So the output you're looking for is an array of boolean value that you will map to the original objects by index?

Comment: @ericgio I can approach this by having array of boolean value, and I found that to be an easy first implementation but would having an object with the key values showing where it didn't match be a better approach?

Comment: "better" is in the eye of the beholder. No one can tell you want is better without you telling us what you're optimizing for. Some people optimize for least number of lines of code. Some people optimize for legibility and maintainability.

Comment: @HereticMonkey fair enough. I am going for maintainability/scalability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to go about this. Utils like lodash can also help make the code cleaner.

Without using lodash, you can use the findIndex function on the array in order to figure out if the object exists or not and return true if the index is greater than -1

```js
const testarr = [
  {
    Account: "1110-000",
    Description: "Cash - Operating",
    Amount: "-2,733,864.88",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
  {
    Account: "1116-000",
    Description: "Cash in Trust",
    Amount: "35,431.85",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
  {
    Account: "1170-000",
    Description: "Petty Cash",
    Amount: "0",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
];

const toDB = {
    Code: "cat",
    ID: "cat12345"
};

const testCheck = {
  Code: toDB.Code,
  Year: "2020",
  Month: "1",
  ID: toDB.ID,
};

const confirmTheSame = (arr, obj) => {
    const today = new Date()
    const currentYear = today.getFullYear().toString()
    const currentMonth = today.getMonth().toString()
    const index = arr.findIndex(x => x.Year === currentYear && x.Month === currentMonth && x.Code === obj.Code && x.ID === obj.ID)
    return index > -1 ? true : false
};

const result = confirmTheSame(testarr, testCheck)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you think you'll only be comparing a specific set of 4 keys, but here's a generalized answer that should allow you to compare an arbitrary number of keys in `testCheck`:

```
function confirmTheSame(obj) {
  // `Id` and `ID` keys are different in the 'test' and 'check' objects,
  // so normalize them here. You could skip this if you know the keys will 
  // always match.
  const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key.toLowerCase()]: obj[key],
  }), {});

  // Use `Array.every` to check that all the values for the given object match.
  return Object.keys(testCheck).every((key) => (
    // Normalize the key here as well.
    newObj[key.toLowerCase()] === testCheck[key]
  ));
}
```

Full sample:

```js
let testarr = [
  {
    Account: "1110-000",
    Description: "Cash - Operating",
    Amount: "-2,733,864.88",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
  {
    Account: "1116-000",
    Description: "Cash in Trust",
    Amount: "35,431.85",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
  {
    Account: "1170-000",
    Description: "Petty Cash",
    Amount: "0",
    Code: "cat",
    Year: "2020",
    Month: "1",
    ID: "cat12345",
  },
];

let toDB = { code: "cat", id: "cat12345" };
let testCheck = {
  Code: toDB["code"],
  Year: "2020",
  Month: "1",
  Id: toDB["id"],
};

function confirmTheSame(obj) {
  const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key.toLowerCase()]: obj[key],
  }), {});

  return Object.keys(testCheck).every((key) => (
    newObj[key.toLowerCase()] === testCheck[key]
  ));
}

console.log(testarr.map(confirmTheSame));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In your opinion would you say having the output in the array format you have here is better approach than in object with key value - where value is the indx of where it didn't match? obj={Code:0, Year:1}. Trying to figure out which way is "faster" to show the user where the error happened. Or if I should be showing that much detail at all

Comment: @shan: I don't know; you haven't explained how you're using the results, so I can't make a recommendation. In any case, I think that's a separate question.